# Como Insertar audioPlayer en grid, Genexus for smart devices

Tags: android, genexus, programación-móvil, genexus15

Quiero que mi chat tenga este aspecto cuando envió un audio. ([DocumentaciónGX](https://youtu.be/vbuKKvBws44?t=21))

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no sé que propiedad, evento o configuración debo tocar para aplicar este aspecto. Si dejo los valores por defecto, al presionar el botón ***Play*** en el grid se reproduce el audio en pantalla completa. ¿Cómo puedo agregar un audioPlayer y que no se reproduzcan los audios en pantalla completa?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.

Comment: AyudaA, una pista!!

Comment: No queda muy claro que codigo estas utilizando. Probaria con el Audio API, doc : https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?20114,HowTo%3A+Using+Audio+in+Smart+Devices

Comment: @fpanizza Estoy cargando los datos con un grid basado en una transacción por lo que no necesitó programar nada en el event load. Inserto los atributos al grid como están en la transacción, estoy mostrando el audio de dos maneras, desde un atributo tipo audio "MensajeAudio"y con un atributto tipo blobfile (rectángulo de color rojo), cuando presiono blobfile se reproduce el audio en background, pero no hay audioplayer. La otra manera que puedo cargar los datos del chat seria con un grid basado en un SDT, pero no sé si pueda agregar el audioPlayer con slider a ese SDT en el grid.